# Can Diesel change schema at runtime?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

Is it possible for `diesel` to listen and change its schema at runtime? Like for example if table is added during runtime, can we detect change and create an appropriate table using `table!` macro after program has started?

Comment: Although I don't know the specifics about Diesel's workings, macros are expanded at compile time so I doubt what you're asking for will work.

Comment: Probably, but how does schema migration work then?

Comment: @DanielFath I think [each migration is run via a separate tool](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/blob/master/diesel_cli/README.md).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The schema is determined at compile time. After migrating your database you need to recompile your application.